# what is the difference of four ways of sending httpRequest by browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, browser

As far as I know, there are four ways of sending httpRequest by browser .

- Type url in browser address bar directly
- through form element of Html
- through ajax
- through javascript such as  'windown.location.href'

I want to ask what are the differences of that four ways of sending httpRequest.
For example, I know type url in browser will build tcp connection. And ajax will use XMLHttprequest object. What about form,it use XMLHttprequest too ? and what about window.location.href？and ......

Comment: It all results in an HTTP request in the end. There is no big difference at that level.

Comment: Is it necessary to know further level ,I want to know more details, or how can i get these knowledge about further level,thank you!

Comment: An introduction: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: @Kaiido thanks,I will read it

Answer (score 1):

> Type url in browser address bar directly

Causes browser to navigate

> through form element of Html

Causes browser to navigate

> through ajax

Sent in background

> through javascript such as 'windown.location.href'

Causes browser to navigate

You missed img elements (loads a dependent resource), script elements (ditto), iframes, objects, audio elements, video elements, link elements with rel=stylesheet (ditto, ditto, ditto, etc) and a variety of others.

> And ajax will use XMLHttprequest object.

Unless it uses JSONP, fetch, a hidden iframe, or some other technique.

> What about form,it use XMLHttprequest too ?

No.

---

This doesn't begin to cover differences in the actual format of the request (such as varying Accept headers or GET vs POST).

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,but at least ,the AJAX will have some difference,because it can update the user interface without reloading the entire browser page. can you tell some difference?

Comment: @Zuckjet — Err. The difference is that it doesn't cause the browser to navigate and it does send the request in the background.

Comment: " it does send the request in the background ". I am a little confused ,if it does send the request in the background , ajax how to update part interface?

Comment: With JavaScript. Or don't update it. Ajax just means sending an HTTP request in the background with JS.

Answer (score -2):

### through form element of Html

1. You can send data through form using method POST and action so that time u can send data or URL through the form element of HTML

### through javascript such as 'windown.location.href'

1. window.location.href returns the href (URL) of the current page
2. The window.location object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page.